# Mocking mongoose validators with jest

Tags: node.js, mongodb, unit-testing, mongoose, jestjs

I'm testing a mongoose model's validation, while trying to mock a validator, the model still has the reference to the original function, so the validation keeps calling the original function.

I want to test that the validator function get's called, however since the validator goes to the db I need to mock it.

This is my model:

```
const { hasRequiredCustoms } = require('../utils/validators')

const ProductSchema = new Schema({
  customs: {
    type: [String],
    validate: hasRequiredCustoms // <- This is the validator
  }
})

const Product = mongoose.model('Product', ProductSchema)

module.exports = Product
```

The original validators:

```
module.exports = {
  hasRequiredCustoms(val) {
    console.log('Original')
    // validation logic
    return result
  },
  //etc...
}
```

This is the mock for validators:

```
const validators = jest.genMockFromModule('../validators')

function hasRequiredCustoms (val) {
  console.log('Mock')
  return true
}

validators.hasRequiredCustoms = hasRequiredCustoms

module.exports = validators
```

And the test:

```
test('Should be invalid if required customs missing: price', done => {
  jest.mock('../../utils/validators')

  function callback(err) {
    if (!err) done()
  }

  const m = new Product( validProduct )
  m.validate(callback)
})
```

Every time I run the tests the console logs the Original. Why is the reference still going back to the original module? seems like I'm missing some super essential concept of how require works or the way mongoose stores the validators references.

Thanks for the help.